# How to escape '/' in django urls

Tags: django, django-views, django-urls

I am working on a project that generates dynamic urls
for eg if you type **mysite.com/<yourtexthere>** The site should generate a url with **mysite.com/yourtexthere** (where yourtext here is a slug of a model)and I am able to do that but the problem arises when I put something like this **mysite.com/yourtexthere/moretext**, Django doesn't match it with any of my existing URL patterns and gives me 404.

I wanted to ask is there a way by which I can treat '/' as just another character and generate unique url **mymysite.com/yourtexthere/moretext** where **yourtexthere/moretext** is now the slug.

**views.py**

```
def textview(request, slug):
    obj, created= Text.objects.get_or_create(slug=slug, defaults={'text':'', 'password':'123'})
    return render(request, 'text/textpage.html', {'obj' : obj, 'created' : created})
```

**urls.py**

```
# Only patterns
urlpatterns = [
    path('', home, name='home'),
    path('<slug:slug>/', textview, name='textview'),
]
```

Comment: please comment if you need any more info

Answer (score 1):

From Django [models docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/fields/):

> A slug is a short label for something, containing only letters, numbers, underscores or hyphens.

So the 404 is actually correct, maybe use another field.

Answer (score 0):

Django path converters match strings in the input URL using regex.
The default path converters are pretty basic - [source code](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/_modules/django/urls/converters/).

The `slugConverter` matches any string that only contains characters, numbers, and dashes, not forward slashes. In string `yourtexthere/moretext` the largest substring it will match is `yourtexthere`.

The `pathConverter` matches a string containing any type of character, so the result can contain a forward slash. It will match all of `yourtexthere/moretext`. So change your `urlpatterns` to this:

```
# Only patterns
urlpatterns = [
    path('', home, name='home'),
    path('<path:slug>/', textview, name='textview'),
]
```

The `pathConverter` will match all special characters. If you don't want this you can create your own custom converter with a regex tailored to your needs. For example, you could simply extend the `slugConverter` to also match strings with forward slashes.

```
class SlugPathConverter(StringConverter):
    regex = '[-a-zA-Z0-9_/]+'
```